# Guru donut tutorial icing selection mesh error

Tags: mesh, error

[image: **after shift+b>ESC>P **]

I made the icing just like what he said in the video(Selected half of the donut with alt+z mode > shift+B > ESC > P), but my icing doesn't fully cover top of the donut. I think it intersects with donut object below. At first, I ignored and kept go on but when I tried to make thickness of it, It makes the thing worse. I don't know what to do.

[image: icing with thicknessstrong text]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: There are a few things that might have happened, however...., and I have given this recommendation before - when doing the donut tutorial, if things go wrong, it's never a bad idea to close the whole project and start again. The repetition will make you much more acquainted with blender's systems (object mode, edit mode, hotkeys, etc...) and will make you much more comfortable using the program and much faster as a whole. As you progress, you will learn what causes what "error", but I think it's better up front to simply get familiar with using blender and it's general workflow.

Comment: and in addition to Christopher's comment i would recommend NOT to do it EVER in another way than the tutorial describes it (if you are a bloody beginner). I did this several times because i thought "whatever, i can move it with G -> X - i have no idea why he goes in edit mode for that - that's waste of time to go in edit mode and move it and then leave edit mode again". This LOOKS like the same (position of the object is the same) but this makes a HUGE difference because the origin point is totally different, which will cause different results if you rotate, scale...etc. afterwards